# uiwebview is not showing PDF properly as showing in safari

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I am having a strange issue. UIwebview is not showing PDF file properly as it shows when I load the PDF file from web URL or in safari browser.

http://www.winsolz.com/temp/2.jpg

I am using the following code to open the PDF from local system.

```
NSString *pathFOrPDF = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page%@", strPDFNumber] ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathFOrPDF];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[myWebview loadRequest:request];      
[myWebviewLandscape loadRequest:request];
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if this will help but you might try setting the web view's `scalesPageToFit` property and see if that adjusts the sizing.

Comment: I am already doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it would fix your case but I had a pdf showing in safari and not showing in a `UIWebView` and my problem was that the file extension was not correct. I appended a `.pdf` at the end of the local file url and started working.
I've noticed that safari check also content types so maybe it is working on safari as you provide a remote url?

Answer (score 0):

this might help.

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
NSString*fileName= @"About_Downloads";
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path     isDirectory:NO]];
[webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
[webView loadRequest:request];
[self.view addSubview:webView]
```